# Echo a comma on all but the last value? (result from mysql_fetch_array)

Tags: php

How do I echo a comma on all but the last value? Here's my code:

```
while ($servdescarrayrow = mysql_fetch_array($servdescarray)) {

    ECHO $servdescarrayrow['serv_desc'].",";
}
```

Shouldn't this work:

```
$i = 0;

while ($servdescarrayrow = mysql_fetch_array($servdescarray)) {

    $count = count($servdescarrayrow);
    if ($i < $count) {
    echo $servdescarrayrow['serv_desc'].",";
    $i++;
    }
    else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You may be able to keep track using something like http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php or use prepending in combination with a boolean.

Comment: Your edit would not work. You're counting the fields in a single ROW of data, not the total number of rows in the result set. For that you need `mysql_num_rows($servdescarray))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$count = 0;
while ($servdescarrayrow = mysql_fetch_array($servdescarray)) {
    if ($count++ > 0) echo ",";
    echo $servdescarrayrow['serv_desc'];
}
```

Comment: This is backwards to the OP's requirements. You're eliminating the FIRST comma. he wants to eliminate the LAST comma.

Answer (score 11):

Another option:

```
$values = array();
while ($servdescarrayrow = mysql_fetch_array($servdescarray)) {
    $values[] = $servdescarrayrow['serv_desc'];
}

echo implode(',', $values);
```

Comment: "Another option"? It's the *only* sane option, methinks. :)

Comment: repeated string concatenation with an rtrim afterwards works just as well. No idea which one would be more efficient, but that's usually not a concern in php anyways.

Comment: @zrvan why do you think so? in fact, involving an array when you have strings for both input and output is just redundant.

Comment: This seems to still add a comma at the end.

Comment: @andrew: only if the last value pushed has a comma in it already. implode() would only put a comma between two elements, not after the last one.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel joining a series of items, most often basic strings or numbers, with a delimiter (but not adding one at the end) is what `implode()` is for. Involving an array in a case like this, where we have a series of strings, should be the natural course of action. Also, manageability over time, see my comment for http://stackoverflow.com/a/8312416/1025411.

Comment: Ok, using a dinky 1 million iteration loop, I get 0.524 seconds for array push + implode, and 0.300 seconds for string concatenation. "big" diff, but only for very long loops. For a few hundred db records, the difference is going to be utterly insignificant.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [rtrim](http://php.net/rtrim) on your output. For example:

```
$output = '';

while ($servdescarrayrow = mysql_fetch_array($servdescarray)) {    
    $output .= $servdescarrayrow['serv_desc'].",";
}

echo rtrim($output, ',');
```

Comment: Overly complicated compared to `implode()`.

Comment: How so? Wheter you initiate an array and implode or initiate a string and trim it .. it's just as much lines of code.

Comment: The complication isn't the number of lines, but the manageability of the code. Granted if this snippet is all we have to work with, it's fine, but as a practice -- say you want to use a different separator later on, this *kind* of solution leads to complications, more places to make changes and increased difficulty to gain a good oversight of the code.

Answer (score 1):

you can remove the last comma after generating the string like so:

```
$str = '';
while ($servdescarrayrow = mysql_fetch_array($servdescarray)) {
   $str .= $servdescarrayrow['serv_desc'].",";
}
$str = substr($str, 0, strlen($str) - 1);
echo $str;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array();
while ($servdescarrayrow = mysql_fetch_array($servdescarray))
    $array[] = $servdescarrayrow['serv_desc'];
ECHO implode(',', $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$started = null;
while ($servdescarrayrow = mysql_fetch_array($servdescarray)) 
{
  ECHO $started.$servdescarrayrow['serv_desc'];
  if ( ! isset($started))
  {
    $started = ",";
  }
}
```

Comment: Won't `isset($started)` always return true?

Comment: It would be better to change $started into a boolean. Thus, start with it being false, than set it true on the first run and prepend a comma when it is true. (Or do not include the if at all but just set it to the comma and initialize it on an empty string instead of null.)

Comment: isset is the fastest comparison (period)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible way.  Not very graceful, but does the job:

```
$Ix = 0;
while ($servdescarrayrow = mysql_fetch_array($servdescarray)) {
    if ($Ix > 0)
        echo ",";
    $Ix++;
    echo $servdescarrayrow['serv_desc'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$i = 0;
$c = mysql_num_rows ( 
while ($servdescarrayrow = mysql_fetch_array($servdescarray)) {
    $i++;
    if ( $i < mysql_num_rows ) echo $servdescarrayrow['serv_desc'].",";
    else echo $servdescarrayrow['serv_desc'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
if ($servdescarryrow = mysql_fetch_array($servdescarray)) {
    echo $servdescarryrow;
}

while ($servdescarrayrow = mysql_fetch_array($servdescarray)) {
    ECHO ",".$servdescarrayrow['serv_desc'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$out = $mydb->getOne("SELECT group_concat(serv_desc) FROM table");
```

where $mydb is a database class, getOne() is a helper function returning first col of the first row and group_concat() output is limited to 1024 bytes but can be altered by setting appropriate variable.

But of course an average enthusiast from this site will always use generic PHP for such a task, as nobody will tell him there are more intelligent ways.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering why there was a dozen answers to your first question and noone to answer the edited part.

Nope, it shouldn't work. Because $servdescarrayrow variable represents only **one** row and you and thus the whole code makes no sense.

Although you *can* involve the number of *returned records* into process and get desired result, I doubt you really need that.

Not to mention that with the way you echo, you will always have the trailing comma anyway.