# How to do something different for the last item in an array (from mysql_fetch_array)?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make sure that commas go after all of the items EXCEPT for the last one - I am trying to figure out how to calculate out what the last item is for variable lists. I decided to try to use count($variablename) but it doesn't seem to work.

Is there something wrong with my syntax?

```
$servicearray = mysql_query("select serv_id from org_serv_xref where org_id='".$org_id."'");

  $servi = 0;

while ($servicearrayrow = mysql_fetch_array($servicearray)) {
    $servdescarray = mysql_query("select serv_desc from service where serv_id='".$servicearrayrow['serv_id']."'");

while ($servdescarrayrow = mysql_fetch_array($servdescarray)) {
    if ($servi < 5 OR $servi < count($servdescarrayrow)) {
   ECHO $servdescarrayrow['serv_desc'].",";
   $servi++;
    }
    else if ($servi == 5 OR $servi == count($servdescarrayrow)) {
        echo $servdescarrayrow['serv_desc'];
        $servi++;
    }
    else {
        $servi = 0;
        break 2;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I saw no other real way to do it.

Comment: You are asking an X-Y question. The real question is "How can I join an array of elements with a comma (,) and have the result be a string?" And there are built-in functions for that (sadly, poorly named in PHP).

Comment: Additionally, this code is open to SQL Injection Attacks.

Comment: I will insert code to prevent attacks later. And implode() did not seem to work (for some reason a comma was added to the end)

Comment: See Marc B's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312374/echo-a-comma-o-all-but-the-last-value (or any of the other ones)

Comment: Is it just me or is this the tenth time I've seen this code?

Answer (score 0):

Because you're starting `$servi` at `0`.  It will always be less than the count of the array.  If you start it at `1` it should work the way you expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

change your query to

```
$servicearray = mysql_query("select GROUP_CONCAT(serv_id) from org_serv_xref where org_id='".$org_id."'");
```

now sql builds the nice comma delimited list for you :)

Answer (score 0):

As near as I can figure, your trying to do something like this (although I could be totally wrong):

```
// Initialise vars
$lastid = '';
$items = array();

// Do the query
$query = "SELECT serv_desc, serv_id
          FROM service
          WHERE serv_id IN (
            SELECT serv_id
            FROM org_serv_xref
            WHERE org_id='".$org_id."'
          )
          ORDER BY serv_id";
$servdescarray = mysql_query($query);

while ($servdescarrayrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($servdescarray)) {
  // We've reached the next ID, echo the result of the last one.
  if ($lastid != $servdescarrayrow['serv_id']) {
    $lastid = $servdescarrayrow['serv_id'];
    if (count($items)) {
      echo implode(',',$items);
      $items = array();
    }
  }
  if (count($items) == 5) { // We don't want more than 5 items
    continue;
  } else  { // Add an item to the results
    $items[$servdescarrayrow['serv_desc']];
  }
}

// Make sure we get the last one
if (count($items)) {
  echo implode(',',$items);
}
```