# How to remove comma in while loop?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a while loop that is as follows:

```
<?php while(has_sub_field('available_locations')): ?>

    <a href="<?php the_sub_field('location_url'); ?>"><?php the_sub_field('locations'); ?></a>,

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

The problem is that Last Location has also comma with it. For example:

> California, Texas,

But I would like to look it like this:

> California, Texas

Since this is containing both HTML and PHP codes, should I store in a variable and use rtrim to cut the last comma, or there is something better solution for it. If I put this in variable, personally I think this is not good solution. Please do respond.

Update: The question is not about only removing last character rather it contains an anchor tag which if I store in a variable, then it is not creating hypertext.Like

> [Google](https://www.google.co.in)

But after storing it in variable, the result is like this:

> https://www.google.co.in Google

Comment: Ultimatly you either need to know when you're at the end, or assign your results to an array so you can work with a finite set of values.

Comment: I think this is not a duplicate question. The question is not about only removing last character rather it contains an anchor tag which if I store in a variable, the it is not creating hypertext.

Comment: Show the HTML source code of the "https://www.google.co.in Google".

Comment: <p>Offert dans la ou les régions suivantes : 
    http://ctfrandev.com/fr/promotions/?regions=491Québec<a href=""></a>
    </p>

Comment: You can be certain that this question is a duplicate on SO.  I'm at the cricket so I can't help to search.  Start with variable as empty string.  Echo it.  After first iteration overwrite variable as comma.  Such simple tasks are duplicates on SO.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312374/echo-a-comma-on-all-but-the-last-value-result-from-mysql-fetch-array @lawrence please close.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705814/stripping-last-comma-from-a-foreach-loop

Answer (score 3):

Use [PHP `substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function.

Example:

```
`substr("abcdef", 0, -1);  // returns "abcde"`
```

So in your case collect all output HTML code to the variable `$links` and then cut off the last character using `substr` and print it with `echo`:

```
<?php 
$links = '';
while(has_sub_field('available_locations')){ 
   $links .= '<a href="'. the_sub_field('location_url') .'">'.  the_sub_field('locations') .'</a>,';
}
echo substr($links, 0, -1);
?>
```

Or use build an array and use [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
<?php 
$links = [];
while (has_sub_field('available_locations')) { 
   $links[] = '<a href="'. the_sub_field('location_url') .'">'.the_sub_field('locations').'</a>';
}
echo implode(', ', $links);
?>
```

**EDIT**
Apparently the function used to generate the URL sends its output directly to the browser which cause broken HTML links.
To avoid such situation use [PHP Output Control Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) that catch the output and enable the data/string manipulations.

```
<?php
ob_start(); // Turn on output buffering
while(has_sub_field('available_locations')){
  '<a href="'. the_sub_field('location_url') .'">'.  the_sub_field('locations') .'</a>,';
}
$links = ob_get_contents(); // Get the contents of the output buffer
ob_end_clean(); // Clean (erase) the output buffer and turn off output buffering

echo substr($links, 0, -1); // removal of the last character, the comma.
?>
```

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thanks for update! Good to see different approaches with same results.

Comment: Ya could even do it with ob_start() ob_end_clean() if ya mad. ;p

Comment: @LawrenceCherone No guys, it's not workings. It basically removes the comma, but it's  directly showing the url. Anchor tag is not working.

Comment: And how the code behave before? What was the output of your original code?

Comment: The anchor tag is used to create a hyper text, but after using your code, the url and Name are seperated. It is not creating hypertext.

Comment: I do not see any syntax error to break the output html code of the anchor. What is the exact output of one anchor?

Comment: @ino See my update on the question.

Comment: @Umar I have added the output buffering to the solution as suggested LawrenceCherone. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to collect all your strings in an array, and use implode to join them.

```
<?php

$links = array();
while( has_sub_field( 'available_locations' ) )
{
  $links[] = '<a href="'.the_sub_field('location_url').'">'.the_sub_field('locations').'</a>';
}
echo implode( ', ', $links );
```

Comment: It will directly show the url. So, it.s not working.

Comment: Ah crazy wordpress, ok this answer is junk then,

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using ACF plugin, to trim the last comma, you can use `rtrim()` function with `get_sub_field()` of ACF or merge all links like bellow.

```
<?php
    $links = array();
    while( has_sub_field( 'available_locations' ) )
    {
      $links[] = '<a href="'.get_sub_field('location_url').'">'.get_sub_field('locations').'</a>';
    }
    echo implode( ', ', $links );
?>
```